# Gravity Forms - Update a field with a new value using a filter

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm using Gravity Forms and I need to update a single field value using a filter. Currently I am using this function and it works great.

```
add_filter( 'gform_addon_field_value_10_3', function ( $field_value, $form, $entry, $field_id ) {
    return 'your new value';
}, 10, 4 );
```

This works great because the form id & the field id is set in the filter itself.

However, when I write this as a general function, I cannot get the field value updated and there's an error. I tried many things and couldn't figure it out. The GF documentation also doesn't seem to help on this matter. Here's the code I have right now.

```
add_filter( 'gform_addon_field_value', function ( $field_value, $form, $entry, $field_id ) {
 
    if ( $form == '18' && $field_id == '12' ) {
        return "yes" ;
    }
    else {
        return "no" ;
}

}, 10, 4 );
```

This does not update the field. Can anyone please help? Would appreciate it very much.

Comment: `$form` is an array containing all the form properties, so you need to replace `$form == '18'` with `rgar( $form, 'id' ) == '18'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_addon_field_value', function ( $field_value, $form, $entry, $field_id ) {
    if ( $form == '18' && $field_id == '12' ) {
        return $field_value = "yes" ;
    }
    else {
        return $field_value = "no" ;
    }
}, 10, 4 );
```